# Alfresco JavaScript API - Copy file

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am developing a web project that uses Alfresco as CMS, and I have just discovered the Alfresco Javascript API.

How to copy a file from an specific Alfresco folder to another folder using Alfresco Javascript API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code for coping node in using alfresco javascript.

```
           newNode = node.copy(destNode);
```

The "newNode" object will contain new node object and destNode and node where you want to copy the node.

Below is thr link for alfresco javascript api documentation which will be use full for you for this kind of operation.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/5.0_JavaScript_API

Comment: You might also want to reference the [ScriptNode javadoc](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html#copy(org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptNode)), which has a bit more detail